# Guice @Named Annotations don't work for same objects

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, guice, dropwizard

I am developing an application where I am using Guice alongwith Dropwizard. I am trying to create two different Jersey clients (with different configurations), so that I can use it for different purpose. I am trying to do with Guice's @Named Annotation. However, it returns the same object irrespective of the String specified in the @Named annotation.

Below is my code. The Module class looks like this:

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named ("clientA")
    public Client providesClientA(Provider<AppConfiguration> appConfigProvider, Environment env) {
        log.info("Inside provider of Client A");
        JerseyClientConfiguration configuration = appConfigProvider.get().getJerseyClientConfigurationA();
        configuration.setTimeout(Duration.seconds(10));
        final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment).using(configuration).using(environment)
            .build(environment.getName());
        return client;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named ("clientB")
    public Client providesClientB(Provider<AppConfiguration> appConfigProvider, Environment env) {
        log.info("Inside provider of Client B");
        JerseyClientConfiguration configuration = appConfigProvider.get().getJerseyClientConfigurationB();
        configuration.setTimeout(Duration.seconds(125));
        final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment).using(configuration).using(environment)
            .build(environment.getName());
        return client;
    }

}
```

The class where these two clients are getting injected looks as follows:

```
public ClassApp {
    private Client clientA;
    private Client clientB;

    @Inject
    public ClassApp(@Named ("clientA") Client clientA,
              @Named ("clientB") Client clientB) {
        this.clientA = clientA;
        this.clientB = clientB;
    }

    public void printClients() {
         log.info("Client A is " + clientA);
         log.info("Client B is " + clientB);
    }
}
```

Here, it will print either "Inside provider of Client A" or "Inside provider of Client B". And the values of clientA and clientB in printClients() method will be same.

If, sometimes, it prints both i.e "Inside provider of Client A" and "Inside provider of Client B", then it will throw an IllegalArgumentException as mentioned below.

```
Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A metric named org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager.AutomatedThresholdApplication.available-connections already exists
while locating javax.ws.rs.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=clientA).
```

I tried the same with String annotated with different names. It would also give the same String, irrespective of annotation.

I am expecting different clients when annotated with "clientA" and "clientB", but after trying a lot and searching on the internet, I think that is not really achievable. Or is there anything I am missing here?

Any pointers or suggestions or workaround around this problem would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your configuration of Guice with `@Named` is correct; there is no reason that your two injections would use the same `@Provides` method implementation. I don't think this is a problem with Guice. Can you try rerunning your test but logging [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) instead of implicitly using `clientA.toString()` in your log, and the same with `clientB`? If those are identical, is is possible that your client builder would return the same instance twice?

Comment: Additional note: It seems your error message might simply be from reusing the Environment object between two clients, as in [DropWizard GitHub issue #832](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/832).

Comment: Logging with `System.identityHashCode()` prints the same hash code for both the objects. I think only one Client provider is getting called for both the objects. Is there anyway this can be solved?

Comment: This is getting really weird. Running the same code multiple times produces different result. Sometimes, it creates same `Client` for both annotations. Other times, it tries to create two different `Client` and ends up throwing an `IllegalArgumentException: A metric named org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager.AutomatedThresholdApplication.available-connections already exists`

Comment: try changing `.build(environment.getName())` to `.build(environment.getName() + "." + "clientA")` and `.build(environment.getName() + "." + "clientB")` respectively.

Comment: also might need to change the [HttpClientMetricNameStrategy](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-client/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java#L278)

Comment: Please provide info on how you initialise your app + configuration and what you use as a guice integration (there are numerous 3rd party libs that do that for you, however you could also do that yourself). Jeff is right, this should really just work. The exception that you see is simply from reusing the metrics and both clients registering the same gauge (I think) which at runtime will cause the duplication and exception.

Comment: It doesn't work, I have tried it a lot. Mine is a simple dropwizard application alongwith Guice for dependency injection. You could give it a try on the same problem, if you want.

Comment: Please add a standalone example of your application, including a main I can run so I can see what happens. Your example is incomplete as to how everything gets put together.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem while trying to bring multiple strings. I have two Named Providers for String.class defined on the AppModule and I am trying to inject those into private fields. If I inject those parameters on to a two member constructor, correct values get passed.

Comment: I am having the same problem, has op find an solution ?